# Inheritance between class QLayout and class QMainWindow Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have a MainWindow class that inherits from QMainWindow. I have another LayoutWindow class that inherits from QLayout.
When I declare an instance of the LayoutWindow class, I have an error:

> error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ...

I do not understand because QMainWindow inherits from QWidget which inherits from QLayout?

Here is my code :

Class MainWindow :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{//instance class LayoutWindow
layoutwindow=new LayoutWindow();

centralArea = new QWidget;
centralArea->setLayout(layoutwindow);
setCentralWidget(centralArea);
}
```

Class LayoutWindow.h

```
class LayoutWindow : public QLayout{

Q_OBJECT

public:
LayoutWindow();
};
```

class LayoutWindow.cpp

```
LayoutWindow::LayoutWindow(){

 //here is my code
}
```

Would anyone have some idea of ​​my problem?

Comment: `QLayout` indeed an abstract class. You cannot instantiate a `LayoutWindow` class object without implementing pure virtual functions there. And `QWidget` doesn't inherit any other class.

Comment: [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#details) is a quick primer on what to do when subclassing `QLayout`. In my experience though, the existing QLayout-subclasses shipped with Qt are suitable/composable for many needs, but I can't judge for your specific application though.

Answer (score 3):

`QLayout` has pure virtual methods, you have to implement these in a subclass you wish to instantiate.

These are

```
void addItem(QLayoutItem *item);
int count() const;
QLayoutItem * itemAt(int index) const;
QLayoutItem * takeAt(int index);
```

Your assertion that `QWidget` inherits `QLayout` is false, it inherits from `QObject` and `QPaintDevice`, both of which have no base classes. `QWidget` has a layout *member*, which arranges child widgets.

I also don't think that you need a class that derives from `QLayout`. You should instead use a combination of *objects* of existing layout and widget types to arrange your window. You should have, as part of the QT install, a tool for visually designing windows, `QDesigner.exe`.

Comment: I would like to keep the same MainWindow, but depending on the function selected in the interface, I would like to change the Layout inside the MainWindow. That's why I would like to have different classes that manage the layout.

Comment: @Thomas1314 If you just want to add or remove child widgets at runtime, you can do that without a custom `QLayout` subclass. If you have totally different sets of widgets, see [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood correctly. I create my LayoutWindow class that inherits from QStackedWidget. I call this class in the MainWindow class and I display my buttons, label ... that's it?

Comment: No, you don't have a `LayoutWindow` class *at all*. `MainWindow` might have a *member* `QStackedWidget *`, which it add various child widgets to. I *strongly* encourage you to learn the Qt visual design tools to make static forms with, they does all the tedious setup *for you*. Have a look at the Qt example programs